# Integrating functions of the distance to the boundary

Tags: real-analysis

Say $\Omega$ is $C^2$ bounded domain and take $d$ to be the distance to the boundary function on $\Omega$. Define $f(x)=|\ln(d(x))|$. Is $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ for all $p\geq 1$?

Away from the boundary the function is bounded and close to the boundary we should be able to parameterise and $d(x)$ should be something like $x_i$, so basically "linear". Now since $\ln(x)$ is integrable on $(0,1]$ I would like to conclude that this is true. How would one argue this rigorously?